# Can't see a cloned GitHub repository in OS X localhost directory

Tags: macos, git, apache, github, localhost

I have my Apache server running under localhost on OS X, as per [this guide.](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/)

I recently tried cloning the private repository for my website from my GitHub account to my ~/Sites/ folder, but it does not show up when I navigate to localhost/~USER/ in Chrome.

At first I thought it was a problem with Git in general, but I cloned a number of other repos, both public and private, and all of those show up fine.

If I create a new folder and copy the files into it, then that is viewable from localhost, but  this breaks my repo. However, if I copy the files using `cp -rp ./source-directory/. /new-directory/`, the .git files are copied but the folder is still unviewable from localhost.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Too many questions. It's not clear whether Apache user has all necessary permissions to view ~/Sites/ folder or not. Also I don't understand why the copying of git repository to another folder breaks it as the git repository is the just set of your project files plus .git folder which contains all necessary information about it.

Comment: Apache has the necessary permissions, as I can see any other repositories that are cloned to the ~/Sites/ directory. It is only the repository belonging to my website that has any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling, I discovered that the issue was due to the presence of a .htaccess file in the repo.

It appears the file in question was messing with the Apache localhost server, which was causing the folder to be inaccessible.